# How can I extract JSON array value from a response body in gitlab yaml?

Tags: json, ansible, gitlab

I have a yml playbook in gitlab and it runs some API requests

This below snippet is where the issue is :

```yaml
- name: Get Deployable Devices info
  uri:
    url: "https://X.X.X.X/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e2743ec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/deployment/deployabledevices?groupDependency=false&limit=1"
    method: GET
    headers:
      X-auth-access-token: "{{ auth_token }}"
      Content-Type: "application/json"
    validate_certs: no
    return_content: yes
  register: versiontimestamp_response
```

This is the output of the `versiontimestamp_response`:

```
"versiontimestamp_response": {
        "items": [
            {
                "name": "fw-itftd-ha", 
                "type": "DeployableDevice", 
                "version": "1692981949723"
            }
        ], 
        "links": {
            "self": "https://X.X.X.X/api/fmc_config/v1/domain/e276abec-e0f2-11e3-8169-6d9ed49b625f/deployment/deployabledevices?offset=0&limit=1&groupDependency=false"
        }, 
        "paging": {
            "count": 1, 
            "limit": 1, 
            "offset": 0, 
            "pages": 1
        }
    }
},
```

I want to extract the version number and put it in a variable to use it later in another request.

I tried this but with no luck

```yaml
- name: Extract version number
  set_fact:
    version_number: "{{ versiontimestamp_response.content.items[0].version }}"
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Please show the structure of the entire `versiontimestamp_response` variable. We have no idea which exact part you debuged above and there is no way to give an answer as it need to fit the data structure.

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator , i edited the question to include what you asked for.

Comment: @VladimirBotka , same issue , i got this error
`fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: builtin_function_or_method object has no element 0\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/builds/slatif/ftd-automation/tasks/main.yml': line 101, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Extract version number\n      ^ here\n"`

Comment: `items` needs to be desambiguated from the `items()` function hence the bracket notation is mandatory here => `{{ versiontimestamp_response['items'].0.version }}`

Comment: For next questions, please make sure you double check the data you paste. Comment from Vladimir is still valid: The output from your debug is not a valid json.